# Draggable and resizable with images workaround?

Tags: jquery, image, draggable, wrapper, resizable

I'm trying to apply the JQuery UI methods .draggable() and .resizable() to an image. These two methods are known to not work together on images, and a common workaround that people suggest for this is to wrap the image in a div and then call .resizable() on that div. The problem is that my image wrapper has separate position and size attributes from my image and nneeds to have a hidden display. This makes the suggested workaround impossible. I imagine a natural reply to this issue would be to wrap my image in another wrap that then gets wrapped in the hidden wrapper, but this introduces a host of other problems into my code. I need a way of applying resizable to my image without creating any wrappers, and without a new "ui-wrapper" div being created automatically. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at http://gridster.net/

They have a nice way to create movable tiles and its better than jquery's method.

Comment: looks nice but the images in my project can't be a part of a grid, they have to be freeform within a container, along with text elements as well.

Comment: Yea you're gonna have to go with wrapping the image somehow. Sorry!